# Initialising KeyValuePair List in C# class constructor, how should it be done?

Tags: c#, database, list, sqlite, key-value

I have a class that contains a List of Key Value Pairs, used as part of an SQLite.Net database. I am using the SQLite.Net Extensions for this, and the tables are all made correctly.

However, when I try to create a new Register to add to the database, I am given a NullReferenceException in the constructor for the Register. I have debugged the code and it seems the issue is with the 'StudentList', when this is removed it all works correctly.

My question is, how should a Key Value Pair list be instantiated? It seems I am messing up somewhere when I initialise it. Below is my register class with the list and constuctor:

```
public class Register
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int RegisterID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean Recurring { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(RegStudent))]
    public List<KeyValuePair<Student, string>> StudentList { get; set; }

    public Register()
    {
        this.StudentList = new List<KeyValuePair<Student, string>>();
    }

    //Adds a student to the Student List for this register, marking the string value as '-', to show the register has not been taken yet.
    //This value will be set to the status of the student, to show them as Present, AWOL, Sick, Late, etc.
    public void addStudent(Student student)
    {
        StudentList.Add(new KeyValuePair<Student, string>(student, "-"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Below is the code where I actually try to create a register. Above this code is a statement that checks to make sure each field actually contains something. I have no idea how this is leading to a null ref. Anything wrong with this?

```
        var student = new Student()
        {
            StudentID = "Setup",
            Username = "Setup",
            FirstName = "Setup",
            LastName = "Setup",
            Image = "check.png"
        };

        //set values from text fields to the new register
        var register = new Register()
        {
            //Change this to something unique, database should automatically set this.
            Name = registerName.Text,
            Type = registerType.Text,
            Location = registerLocation.Text,
            Date = datePicker.Date,
            StartTime = startTimePicker.Time.ToString(),
            EndTime = endTimePicker.Time.ToString(),
            Recurring = switcher.IsToggled,
            StudentList = new List<KeyValuePair<Student, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<Student, string>(student, "-")
            }
        };

        //Do the stuff in comments below for web db upload below adds register to local db.
        var result = database.db.CreateRegister(register);
```

**EDIT:** Added a few more lines of code (above) to show how the register is passed to the db. Below is the stack trace for the exception thrown:

```
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312): Process: com.companyname.RegistrationApp, PID: 2312
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312):     ... 1 more
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312): Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312):   at RegistrationApp.RegisterPage..ctor (Int32 id) <0xdb47ac68 + 0x000bc> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312):   at RegistrationApp.CreateRegisterPage+<OnCreateButtonClicked>d__1d.MoveNext () <0xdb472000 + 0x00933> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-09 14:40:55.959 E/AndroidRuntime( 2312): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Also to add (this may actually be a part of the problem), when adding the register to the database (the point where the exception occurs), this code is used:

```
public Boolean CreateRegister(Register register)
    {
        try
        {
            var newReg = new Register
            {
                Name = register.Name,
                Type = register.Type,
                Location = register.Location,
                Date = register.Date,
                StartTime = register.StartTime,
                EndTime = register.EndTime,
                Recurring = register.Recurring,
                StudentList = register.StudentList
            };
            _connection.Insert(newReg);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any way for this code to cause a NullReferenceException. Is this the actual, real code that you have tested to cause one?

Comment: @Blorgbeard This is the exact code that gives the error, I think the problem is that when I create a register, I do not have a student list to add with it. The student list is populated after the register is created. I thought the constructor I am using prevents NullReferenceException by instantiating the list, but it doesn't seem to prevent the exception. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. The student list is always created as it is populated. What's the exact error (stack-trace included) and which line does it refer to?

Comment: If you can engineer a self-contained code-sample that we can paste into Visual Studio and run (without setting up a bunch of textboxes etc) that demonstrates the error, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I've added the stack trace and shown some more of the code here, can't really split up the project without any views as it's all linked to the views. Thanks for the help so far, I have added the actual method that is called to create register.

Comment: The NRE is being thrown from the constructor of `RegisterPage` that takes an `int` - that's where you should be looking.

Comment: @DStanley wow, I was barking up the wrong tree completely! I was trying to pass in the register ID (an auto-incremented int) to the register page, but was doing it with the register I created, not the register from the database. This threw an exception as the one from the db had an ID, but the other didn't. Fixed this now, and added some safety code. Thanks for the help, it was pretty obvious in the end (once I knew where to look!!).

Comment: @user2283597 glad you got it fixed.